# Simple time profiling - strange times

Tags: c#

I'm trying to profile my code to check how long it takes to execute some parts of my code.

I've wrapped my most time-consuming part of the code in something like that:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
...
... // Here comes the time-consuming part
... 
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).Miliseconds);
```

The program is executing this part of code for couple of seconds (about 20 s) but in console I get the result of something about 800 miliseconds. Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of Miliseconds, use TotalMiliseconds instead.  The current way you have it will only show the current Miliseconds and is very misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you actually wanting the [TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property?  `Milliseconds` returns the milliseconds *component* of the timespan, not the actual length of the timespan in milliseconds.

That said, you probably want to use Stopwatch (as the others said) since it will be more accurate.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question directly ;)  This is why the OP is getting 800 instead of 20k (or rather, probably, 19800)

Comment: Man I didn't even realize what the question was. I just saw how they were profiling and wrote up my answer...

Answer (score 17):

Try using the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class for this.  It was intended for this exact purpose.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// ...
// Here comes the time-consuming part
// ...
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for showing me the Stopwatch class. But Zach showed me exactly where I made the mistake. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Gacek: I would still recommend using Stopwatch.  It's much more reliable, and much more accurate when you get "faster" methods.  (DateTime isn't very accurate for small timings...)

Answer (score 3):

This is a much better way to profile your code.

```
var result = CallMethod(); // This will JIT the method
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    result = CallMethod();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromTick(sw.ElapsedTicks / 5));
```

Comment: Even better is to not count the first iteration - then divide by 4.  That will eliminate the skew from the JIT even more ...

Answer (score 0):

If you instead reference the `TotalMilliseconds` property, you will get the result you were looking for.  But, I think the other answers recommending `Stopwatch` to be a better practice.